# jquery - toggle input values with link and php sessions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, hyperlink, toggle

I have read all sorts of similar Q/A. This may be too specific I suppose.

I would like to toggle input (text) values by "clicking" a voided hyperlink

```
<a id="same" href="javascript:;">link</a>
```

The toggle values are stored in sessions.

So click the link once and value="session". Click again value="". Back and forth. I know its probably simple. I can read jquery. Still learning to write it.

```
$("#same").on("click", function(){
    $("[name='event_contact_name']").val($("[name='<?php echo "session 1"; ?>']").val());
    $("[name='event_contact_lastname']").val($("[name='<?php echo "session 2"; ?>']").val());
    $("[name='event_contact_phone']").val($("[name='<?php echo "session 3"; ?>']").val());
    $("[name='event_contact_email']").val($("[name='<?php echo "session 4"; ?>']").val());
});
```

Comment: Why, but why you PHP `echo` something you can hardcode into JS? What stops you from doing `$("[name='session 1']").val()`

Comment: The sessions are set at this point.  I need to toggle (with a link) the values of the sessions to populate the input fields.  I don't suppose I need to echo.  Thank you for showing me different methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could PHP echo `$_SESSION["something"]` inside a `data-*` attribute of your input elements.  like:

```
data-sessionval="<?= $_SESSION["something"] ?>"
```

Example with anchor toggle

```js
$("#same").on("click", function() {

 var tog = this._sessTog = !this._sessTog;

  $("[data-sessionval]").val(function() {
    return tog ? $(this).data("sessionval") : "";
  });

});
```

```html
<a id="same" href="javascript:;">Use session values</a>

<br>

Name: <input name="event_contact_name" data-sessionval="php echoed here">
last name: <input name="event_contact_lastname" data-sessionval="php echo text">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But using anchors for something **cehckoxes** were invented for - seems odd, so:

```js
$("#same").on("change", function() {

 var ckd = this.checked;

  $("[data-sessionval]").val(function() {
    return ckd ? $(this).data("sessionval") : "";
  });

});
```

```html
<label><input id="same" type="checkbox"> Use session values</label>

<br>

Name: <input name="event_contact_name" data-sessionval="php echoed here">
last name: <input name="event_contact_lastname" data-sessionval="php echo text">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't like the checkbox, use CSS:

```js
$("#same").on("change", function() {

  var ckd = this.checked;

  $("[data-sessionval]").val(function() {
    return ckd ? $(this).data("sessionval") : "";
  });

});
```

```css
[type=checkbox] + span:before {
  margin-right: 10px;
  content: "\2610";
}
[type=checkbox]:checked + span:before {
  content: "\2611";
  color: #0bf;
}
```

```html
<label>
   <input id="same" type="checkbox" hidden>
   <span>Use Session values</span>
</label>

<br> Name: <input name="event_contact_name" data-sessionval="php echoed here">
Last name: <input name="event_contact_lastname" data-sessionval="php echo text">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```